# bluetooth 4.2 is not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, dd, adapter, ubuntu-drivers

I am new in linux family.
Recently i moved windows 10 to ubuntu 20.04 in my new laptop (hp-15s du1030tx) . That time my wifi and bt are not working . I fix my wifi driver problem . And i try to fix my bt problem .I read most of article for fix bt driver . But i can not fix now .
Please help me to enter solution here

input: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce
    Kernel modules: 8821ce
```

input:lsusb

output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 30c9:0013 DJKCVA1BID55JV HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2a7a:9a18  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa23  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

input: `dmesg | grep -i blue`

output:

```
[   82.410951] audit: type=1107 audit(1595147083.983:6400): pid=1011 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=3641 label="snap.chromium.chromium"
[  887.771190] audit: type=1107 audit(1595147889.350:6473): pid=1011 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=5441 label="snap.chromium.chromium"
```

input:usb-devices

output:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=12
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.4.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=05e3 ProdID=0606 Rev=07.02
S:  Manufacturer=ALCOR
S:  Product=USB Hub 2.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=25a7 ProdID=fa23 Rev=02.41
S:  Manufacturer=Compx
S:  Product=2.4G Receiver
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  5 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2a7a ProdID=9a18 Rev=00.01
S:  Manufacturer=CASUE
S:  Product=CASUE USB Keyboard
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=04 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=30c9 ProdID=0013 Rev=00.01
S:  Manufacturer=DJKCVA1BID55JV
S:  Product=HP TrueVision HD Camera
S:  SerialNumber=0001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=10000 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 3.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.4.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command. Nobody knows what is "your bt adapter".

Comment: Why did you run `lspci -knn` without grep? Please fix it. And also please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: this community are so much helpful . I am surprised . advance thanks

Comment: I think this BT adapter is not supported by Linux yet.

Comment: what can do now ? is it fix in future?

Comment: Kernel needs patching. Please add output of `usb-devices`.

Comment: i added input and output  --@Pilot6

Comment: I don't see any BT devices.

Comment: but i have bt driver when i was windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Kensington (Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle) working fine out of the box for Ubuntu 20.04 on my Macbook Pro 16inch. I was able to pair my AirPod Pro's fine.